# Array containing objects is duplicating them rather than overwriting their values

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating a shopping cart app. When the user changes the quantity of an item, the price of the item should be updated along with it. However, in trying to implement this, I've encountered a bug where the items in the shopping cart are being duplicated rather than updated. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

const handleQuantityChange = (e, product) => {

setCart((prevState) => [
  ...prevState,
  ...prevState.map((item) => {
    if (item.id === product.id) {
      return {
        ...item,
        price: item.originalPrice * e.target.value,
        quantity: e.target.value,
      };
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  }),
]);
}
```

Comment: it will really be updated because it's an array.. if you do this `[...items, ...items.map(...)]` then you're basically appending the mapped items to the existing items.

Comment: if you really want to just update it then just remove the first ...prevState.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[...prevState, ...prevState.map()]` is duplicating your list twice (one is the `prevState`, one is `prevState.map()`)

You should modify your code like this

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

const handleQuantityChange = (e, product) => {

setCart((prevState) => [
  ...prevState.map((item) => {
    if (item.id === product.id) {
      return {
        ...item,
        price: item.originalPrice * e.target.value,
        quantity: e.target.value,
      };
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  }),
]);
}
```

Another way without `prevState` but `cart` state

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);

const handleQuantityChange = (e, product) => {

  const updatedCart = cart.map((item) => {
    if (item.id === product.id) {
      return {
        ...item,
        price: item.originalPrice * e.target.value,
        quantity: e.target.value,
      };
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  });

  setCart(updatedCart);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[...prevState, ...prevState.map()]` is duplicated one.

You can find the corresponding item in `prevState` by `find` function and update its price and quantity.

You can update `setCart` function call like the following.

```
    setCart(prevState => {
      const newState = prevState? [...prevState] : [];
      const item = newState.find(x => x.id === product.id);
      let qty = parseFloat(e.target.value);
      qty = isNaN(qty) ? 0 : qty; 
      item.price = item.originalPrice * qty;
      item.quantity = qty;
      return newState;
    });
```